# Get all rows with certain alias

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, mysqli, rows

I would like to get all rows in a table (mysqli) containing certain alias. Then I just wan't to echo the "mission" box of the rows.
I tried the following code to get all "mission"-boxes in li:s.

```
$missions = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT mission FROM missions WHERE alias = '". $alias ."'"));
foreach($missions as $mission){
    echo "<li>". $mission. "</li>";
}
```

But that only echo the first row like:
* Testing
and not like
* Testing
* Testing2
which it should have done. How can I change my code so it echo all missions with the alias that I have chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply `mysqli_fetch_all`! Look here (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an authority on PHP, but maybe this may work?

Instead of creating the alias in the foreach, do it in the mysqli_query function

> mysqli_query($con,"SELECT mission as alias FROM missions WHERE alias =
>   '"... etc